# Strategy to extract structured data with xpath

Tags: javascript, xpath

Is there a pattern to extract structured data from an HTML page using XPath? I'm trying to extract data from one or more HTML tables on a page. XPath makes it easy to find the table(s), but I'm struggling once I've got that far.

I'm currently doing the following:

- Iterate the tables (there may be more than one)
- Iterate the rows within that table
- Iterate the cells within that row
- (Then probably put them in an array and parse the contents)

My code is something like this:

```
var tables = mydoc.evaluate( "//table", mydoc, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null );

table = tables.iterateNext();
while (table)
{
  var rows = mydoc.evaluate("tbody/tr", table, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null);
  row = rows.iterateNext();
  while (row)
  {
    var tds = mydoc.evaluate("td", row, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null)
    td = tds.iterateNext()
    while(td)
    {
      // TODO: store content in an array to process later
      print('*' + td.textContent);
      td = tds.iterateNext();
    }
    row = rows.iterateNext();
  }

  table = iterator.iterateNext();
}
```

This seems a little nasty as all the XPath examples seem to do their processing in one step. There appear to be few non-trivial examples where two types of data (e.g. labels and values in a table) are selected and combined. I can use the following selectors, but I end up with two lists with no structure:

```
//table/tbody/tr/td[@class='label']
//table/tbody/tr/td/a[@class='value']
```

(I know I'm using XPath for HTML parsing for which it wasn't really intended, but it seems to work so far.)

Comment: In XPath 1.0, only node set data type is a not atomic type. It's a set: unordered uniques nodes, not "structured" data type. What you want involves some kind of grouping: for each `//table/tbody/tr` then extract the `td[@class='label']` and `td/a[@class='value']`.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a single XPath expression that selects the wanted nodes.

Answer (score 2):

> There appear to be few non-trivial
>   examples where two types of data (e.g.
>   labels and values in a table) are
>   selected and combined. I can use the
>   following selectors, but I end up with
>   two lists with no structure:
>
> ```
> //table/tbody/tr/td[@class='label'] 
> //table/tbody/tr/td/a[@class='value']
> ```

**Use**:

```
    //table/tbody/tr/td[@class='label']
|
    //table/tbody/tr/td/a[@class='value']
```

This single XPath expression selects all the wanted nodes (all XPath engines I am aware of return the selected nodes in document order). The `|` (union) operator produces the set union of its arguments.

If the (x)Html document has regular structure, you may expect in the returned result every selected `td` element (label) to be followed by its corresponding `a` element (value)

Answer (score 0):

If it's on the main HTML page, you could just do:

```
for(var tables=document.getElementsByTagName("table"),i=0;i<tables.length;++i)
  for(var rows=tables[i].getElementsByTagName("tr"),j=0;j<rows.length;++j)
    for(var cells=rows[j].getElementsByTagName("td"),k=0;k<cells.length;++k)
      print("*"+cells[i].textContent);
```

getElementsByTagName does /not/ return an array - it returns a live NodeList similar to ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE.